# mvn depedency:tree local application

Tags: java, maven

I have an application of the following format

```
protocol/
  pom.xml
service/
  pom.xml
pom.xml
```

`service` `pom.xml` has a dependency on `protocol` and includes it. When I run `mvn dependency:tree` I get a warning that it cannot find resolve the dependency of `protocol`  in `service`. How do I get this local project dependency resolved?

I tried adding another repository

```
<repository>
        <id>my-internal-rep</id>
        <url>file:///path/to/my/root/application</url>
</repository>
```

And tried all kinds of combination for the path (to the root, to the protocol, to the jar file, etc). None of them work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two solutions: If `protocol` and `service` are defined as modules in the root pom, you can run `mvn dependency:tree` in the project root directory.

If you wish to only see the dependency tree of `service`, you first need to run `mvn install` once in the project root directory. This will install the parent pom, `protocol` and `service` in your local maven repository and make it available to all other artifacts.